# String Trim/Substring C#

Tags: string, substring, trim

I have a problem with getting a certain characters in a string. For example, if a person has 2 names in his first name, I'd only like to get the first one.

**First Name**: Jan Edson

**Output**: Jan

I've been trying the `Trim()` method but It only removes extra whitespaces. 
I haven't tried `Substring()` yet.

Are there other ways? Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string firstName = Regex.Match("Jan Edson", @"\w*").ToString();
```

Comment: I actually find this easier. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 4):

You should use `String.Split()` and split by the whitespace character.
This will result in an array with both `Jan` and `Edson`

```
        // The input string
        const string name = "Jan Edson";

        // Split by the spacebar
        var nameParts = name.Split(' ');

        // Will return 'Jan'
        string firstPart = nameParts[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to identify the space

For eg.

```
            String Name = "sdf fsd";
            FirstName = Name .Substring(0, Name.IndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: your String is Name but you are using sa?

Comment: nice catch buddy made a test app just couldn't able to change names :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. One of them is using `String.Split`

```
    string text = "Jan Edson";
    char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
    string firstName = "";
    if (words.Count > 1)
        firstName = word[0];
```